# What does the alphanumeric value mean in an elixir mix lock file?

Tags: elixir

[image: sample of the lock file]

Hello, I'm curious what the value "d42e20054116c49d5242d3ff9e1913acccebe6015f449d6e312a5bc160e79a62" represents in the slice of the lockfile above. I've tried reading through the mix source code and feel like it has something to do with git, but I can't pinpoint it exactly.

The lock-related module in the mix source code has read and write lock methods (https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/5984c6cc29a41d5bc78d49427730c8786d75e2c9/lib/mix/lib/mix/dep/lock.ex#L13) but doesn't say much about the map it deals with. The tests don't seem to hint at what this value represents either: https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/9e40b8f786625b2f036ce9c2467cd0a8ade35ce6/lib/mix/test/mix/dep/lock_test.exs.

I thought it might be a git commit hash (either produced by my machine locally or pulled from the dependency's repo. I didn't find that hash in either place.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a hash, used in the dependency convergence process. Roughly speaking, [`Mix.Dep.Converger`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.10.3/lib/mix/lib/mix/dep/converger.ex) builds a [`:digraph`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/digraph.html) of dependencies and uses topology sort to determine whether the dependencies have diverged or not.

You would not be able to find it in *Elixir/Mix* source code because it’s [delegating to the external converger](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.10.3/lib/mix/lib/mix/dep/converger.ex#L95), which depends on what type of dependency is it. In the case of `:hex` type of dependency, remote is [`Hex.RemoteConverger`](https://github.com/hexpm/hex/blob/v0.20.5/lib/hex/remote_converger.ex).

That said, this value is under full `Hex.RemoteConverger` responsibility, `mix` has zero clue about it. If you would like to provide another dependency source to `mix` you could implement `@behaviour Mix.RemoteConverger` and upon dependency convergence process, your converter implementation would be called with whatever arguments you want.

Comment: FWIW, this is [how I revealed it](https://rocket-science.ru/hacking/2020/05/08/reverse-engineering-for-poor).